# Output? prime factorization

Tags: c

So I have this program and need it to write the output as "96 is 2^5 x 3^1" instead of 2x2x2x2x2x3.

```
    int main() {

        int i, n;

        // Get the user input.
        printf("Please enter a number.\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        // Print header.
        printf("The prime factorization of %d is ", n);

        // Loop through, finding prime factors.
        int cur_factor = 2;
        while (cur_factor < n) {

            // Found a factor.
            if (n%cur_factor == 0) {
                printf("%d x ", cur_factor);
                n = n/cur_factor;

            }

            // Going to the next possible factor.
            else
                cur_factor++;
        }

        // Prints last factor.
        printf("%d.\n", cur_factor);

        return 0;
```

What do I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: A nested loop looks like a good starting point, where the inner loop counts the "power".

Answer (score 1):

```
while (cur_factor < n) {

            // Found a factor.
            while (n%cur_factor == 0) {

                n = n/cur_factor;
               count++;
            }
          while(count--)
          printf("%d x ", cur_factor);
          count=0;

            // Going to the next possible factor.
            else
                cur_factor++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable `power` to keep track of the exponent and print it.

Also use a `while` loop to keep dividing `n` by `cur_factor` until `n` cannot be divided anymore by that factor.

```
    int cur_factor = 2;
    int power = 0;
    while (cur_factor < n) {

        // Found a factor.
        while (n % cur_factor == 0) {
            power++;
            n = n/cur_factor;

        }

        // Going to the next possible factor.
        if (power > 0) 
            printf("%d^%d x", cur_factor, power);
        power = 0;
        cur_factor++;
        }
    }
```